# Ado.net firebird commit insert new lines to table

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, firebird, rdbms

I'm adding new lines to a database for our company's "order list" for each order created, using the firebird ado.net client. The code i've written works fine for listing items, but inserting new ones doesn't appear elsewhere (e.g. in flamerobin). What I think is happening is that the transaction isn't being committed, seeing as it's recognised within my code (can't add duplicate values). 
Code:

```
using (FbConnection fbCon = new FbConnection)
{
    fbCon.Open();
    ***command w/ parameterised command string***
    using (FbTransaction fbTrans = fbCon.BeginTransaction())
    using FbCommand orderCommand = new FbCommand(cmdString, fbCon, fbTrans)
    {
    ***Adding parameters and values***
    try
    {
        int recordsAffected = orderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        fbTrans.Commit();
    }
    catch (FbException E)
    {
    fbTrans.Rollback();
    fbCon.Close();
    throw E
    }
}
```

recordsAffected returns 1 but I am not able to see the updated values in flamerobin or the db management program. Am i missing something?

Comment: Make sure that in the "other program" you also start new transaction - otherwise they could be using an old transaction (started before you added the records) which don't see the new records.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already tried that. The issue is that the transactions return without error, but don't seem to be committing. I think it's  either the ado.net client or something in Visual Studio keeping the connection open? Has anyone else worked with these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this problem, it's in Visual Studio's debugging settings. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/05/dealing-with-local-databases-or-why-your-updates-dont-stick.aspx explains pretty clearly, but basically VS makes a copy of your database in bin/Debug of your project (Ostensibly to not mess with your data) but if you actually need to use/view the data externally, either link your external application to the debug database (e.g. flamerobin). You may also need to set your project database settings to Copy if Newer if you want your updates to stay, as the default setting copies the database into the folder each time you run your c# app.